# Unknown Error With File upload via Webhook

Tags: php, file-upload, webhooks

Am trying to send a file and it's record via webhook to another website which receives the data but am having problem saving the file to a directory am having unkknown error what could the cause be any alternative I can try? This is my log result I logged all the records and file for clarity `

```
[24-Nov-2023 13:28:25 America/New_York] Webhook Data Received: {"emails":[{"email":"peterclark@gmail.com","mail_id":"657070","date":"2023-11-24","time":"13:28:25","file_path":"\/home\/darksbqo\/public_html\/apps\/dragonphly\/files\/file_657070_1700850505_8631.pdf"}],"xfile":{"name":"ckeditor4-export-pdf.pdf","type":"application\/pdf","tmp_name":"\/tmp\/phpwTZwba","error":0,"size":21075}}

2023-11-24 13:28:25 - Webhook Data Received: 
Array
(
    [emails] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [email] => peterclark@gmail.com
                    [mail_id] => 657070
                    [date] => 2023-11-24
                    [time] => 13:28:25
                    [file_path] => /home/darksbqo/public_html/apps/dragonphly/files/file_657070_1700850505_8631.pdf
                )

        )

    [xfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => ckeditor4-export-pdf.pdf
            [type] => application/pdf
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpwTZwba
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 21075
        )

)

[24-Nov-2023 13:28:25 America/New_York] Error moving uploaded file: ckeditor4-export-pdf.pdf. Error code: Unknown, Error message: Unknown error
Error moving uploaded file: ckeditor4-export-pdf.pdf. Error code: Unknown, Error message: Unknown error[24-Nov-2023 13:28:25 America/New_York] Webhook Response: {"success":false,"message":"Email(s) processed successfully","errors":["Error moving uploaded file: ckeditor4-export-pdf.pdf. Error code: Unknown, Error message: Unknown error","Error inserting record into mails table: Column 'file_path' cannot be null"]}

Webhook Response: 
Array
(
    [success] => 
    [message] => Email(s) processed successfully
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => Error moving uploaded file: ckeditor4-export-pdf.pdf. Error code: Unknown, Error message: Unknown error
            [1] => Error inserting record into mails table: Column 'file_path' cannot be null
        )

)
```

And this is my code

```
text/x-generic webhook.php ( PHP script text )

<?php
// Set error reporting for debugging
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
ini_set('log_errors', 'On');
ini_set('error_log', __DIR__ . '/webhook_log.txt');

// Create a database connection
$servername = "servername  is here";
$username = "username is here";
$password = "password is here";
$dbname = "mailgateway";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Log the raw webhook data for debugging
$rawWebhookData = file_get_contents('php://input');
error_log("Webhook Data Received: " . $rawWebhookData);

// Receive and decode webhook data
$webhookData = json_decode($rawWebhookData, true);

// Check if decoding was successful
if ($webhookData === null) {
    // Log the error
    $jsonLastError = json_last_error();
    $jsonLastErrorMessage = json_last_error_msg();
    $logMessage = "Error decoding webhook data. Error code: $jsonLastError, Message: $jsonLastErrorMessage";
    error_log($logMessage);

    // Output a generic error to the response for debugging
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'message' => 'An error occurred while processing the webhook data.']);
    exit; // Stop execution
}

// Initialize response array
$response = ['success' => true, 'message' => 'Email(s) processed successfully', 'errors' => []];

// Prepare and bind the SQL statement for inserting into 'mails' table
$insertMailStmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO mails (email, mail_id, file_path, date, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$insertMailStmt->bind_param("sssss", $email, $mailId, $filePath, $date, $time);

// Log the processed data and errors to webhook_log.txt
$logFile = __DIR__ . '/webhook_log.txt';
$logMessage = PHP_EOL . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' - Webhook Data Received: ' . PHP_EOL . print_r($webhookData, true) . PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents($logFile, $logMessage, FILE_APPEND);

try {
    // Start a database transaction
    $conn->begin_transaction();

    // Process each email data
    foreach ($webhookData['emails'] as $emailData) {
        // Extract data and sanitize
        $email = filter_var($emailData['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $mailId = filter_var($emailData['mail_id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $date = filter_var($emailData['date'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $time = filter_var($emailData['time'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        // Upload  file
        $xfile = $webhookData['xfile']; // Adjust this based on your payload structure
        $filename = 'file_' . $mailId . '_' . time() . '_' . rand(1000, 9999) . '.pdf';  // Adjust the extension accordingly
        $xfilePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/data/uploads/files/' . $filename;

        // Move the payload file to the specified directory
        if (move_uploaded_file($xfile['tmp_name'], $xfilePath)) {
            $filePath = $xfilePath; // Set the file path to the uploaded path
        } else {
            // Log the error details if available
            $errorMessage = error_get_last()['message'] ?? 'Unknown error';
            $errorCode = error_get_last()['type'] ?? 'Unknown';

            // Check if error details are available before logging
            if ($errorMessage !== null && $errorCode !== null) {
                $logMessage = "Error moving uploaded file: " . basename($xfile['name']) . ". Error code: $errorCode, Error message: $errorMessage";
                error_log($logMessage);
                file_put_contents($logFile, $logMessage, FILE_APPEND);
            } else {
                // Log a generic error message if detailed information is not available
                $logMessage = "Error moving uploaded file: " . basename($xfile['name']) . ". Unknown error occurred during file move.";
                error_log($logMessage);
                file_put_contents($logFile, $logMessage, FILE_APPEND);
            }

            // Add error to the response
            $response['success'] = false;
            $response['errors'][] = $logMessage;
        }

        // Bind parameters and execute the prepared statement
        $insertMailStmt->execute();

        // Check for successful insertion
        if ($insertMailStmt->affected_rows <= 0) {
            $response['success'] = false;
            $response['errors'][] = "Error inserting record into mails table: " . $insertMailStmt->error;
        }
    }

    // Commit the database transaction
    $conn->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Rollback the transaction in case of an exception
    $conn->rollback();

    // Log the exception
    $logMessage = "Exception: " . $e->getMessage();
    error_log($logMessage);
    file_put_contents($logFile, $logMessage, FILE_APPEND);

    // Add error to the response
    $response['success'] = false;
    $response['errors'][] = $logMessage;
} finally {
    // Close the prepared statement
    $insertMailStmt->close();
}

// Log the response
error_log("Webhook Response: " . json_encode($response));
file_put_contents($logFile, PHP_EOL . 'Webhook Response: ' . PHP_EOL . print_r($response, true), FILE_APPEND);

// Output the response
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Could the problem be from the data received via webhook or my code? Please review I was supposed to save the file to a directory along side it's records to db. Please help alternative code will do to thanks.

Comment: `having problem saving the file to a directory` what does the error log say about it?

Comment: @Adi please check my log result above am getting unknown error

Comment: Why have you kept this line `$insertMailStmt->execute();` still executable even if an error occurs while moving the file. Did you check the permissions of the directory you are trying to move the file to?

Comment: @Adi yes I checked the permission it's 0755. If the file is moved successfully, the path to the file will be updated else the error (file_path) cannot be null will occur but my main problem is moving the file the permissions are thus /data(0755)/uploads(0777)/files(0777)/

Comment: How about the permissions at `tmp` like `/tmp/phpwTZwba`, does this have correct permissions?

Comment: @Adi There's no tmp directory

Comment: So this `$xfile['tmp_name']` is storing `/tmp/phpwTZwba` path as value right in the var and if you say `There's no tmp directory` then isn't the error pretty obvious?

Comment: @Adi  Yeah so I need to create a tmp directory right? For tmp name or should I use the server tmp directory (which is not wise I think). The tmp_name in the file array comes with /tmp/ does that mean I need to create an actual folder? This file is received via webhook and the data is in the file array

Comment: Actually there's a default tmp directory using `<?php
echo sys_get_temp_dir();
?>`
I got `/tmp`

Comment: _"Yeah so I need to create a tmp directory right?"_ - no; you would need to actually upload a file in the first place. Which currently, you clearly aren't. You are reading the script input from `php://input` and decoding it as JSON, so you must have _sent_ a `Content-Type: application/json` request to begin with. So you _can't_ have performed a HTTP file upload, because that requires `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: You got the _structure_ of the $_FILES entry of a file upload in `$webhookData['xfile']`- but the actual file _data_ is missing in your request. Presumably because you took the contents of $_FILES in the location where you _actually_ received a file upload, encoded it as JSON there, and then sent _that_ to your webhook. Which will of course not transport the actually uploaded file content along. The temp file has been deleted as soon as the script that actually received the file upload, ended. Moving the file out of the upload temp dir needs to happen in _that_ script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you're almost correct @CBroe I was sending the file as json text data instead of handling it as a file just seeing your suggestion but I've fixed this since yesterday. The file is supposed to be sent as a file not as text which I did unintentionally am supposed to specify the it as a file, get the file data and send this data across. I fixed it by modifying my code like this `// Create cURL file object $file = new CURLFile($xfile['tmp_name'], $xfile['type'], $xfile['name']);`  This way I was able to send the file via json webhook instead of sending it as a text format which it's not. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

cut the lines below:

```php
// Prepare and bind the SQL statement for inserting into 'mails' table
$insertMailStmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO mails (email, mail_id, file_path, date, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$insertMailStmt->bind_param("sssss", $email, $mailId, $filePath, $date, $time);
```

and paste them above the line: `$insertMailStmt->execute();`. the result should be:

```php
// Prepare and bind the SQL statement for inserting into 'mails' table
$insertMailStmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO mails (email, mail_id, file_path, date, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$insertMailStmt->bind_param("sssss", $email, $mailId, $filePath, $date, $time);
// Bind parameters and execute the prepared statement
$insertMailStmt->execute();
```

Comment: My problem is with uploading / saving a file i got from webhook not sql

Comment: Why am wondering is because it's woking (file upload / saving) on my main site but it's failing to work receiving the file via webhook to my addon (receiving website).